# Событие обращения к панели разработчика в javascript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли каким-либо способом отслеживать событие обращения пользователя к панели разработчика через js?

Comment: Можно использовать https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

Comment: Хорошего, универсального способа нету.

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _обращением пользователя к панели разработчика через js_?